# Changing variables inside a recursive function

Tags: haskell, recursion

I'm trying to make a game in Haskell. Right now, I'm working on enemy collision: that is, if an enemy collides with the player, the score gets reset to 0 and the enemy dies. However, I just can't quite work out *how*.

I've already considered a `do` block but that's not right (I don't want to return IO). I can't find anything to point me in the right direction, leaving me to wonder if it's even possible...

The (kind of ugly) piece of code I have is this:

```
newEnemies = updateEnemies enemies
    updateEnemies :: [Point] -> [Point]
    updateEnemies [] = []
    updateEnemies (x:xs) | hitPlayer (nextLocation x) = -- TODO: Reset multipliers
                                                        updateEnemies xs
                         | otherwise = nextLocation x : updateEnemies xs
        where
        hitPlayer :: Point -> Bool
        hitPlayer (x, y) | abs (fst newPosition - x) < 10 && abs (snd newPosition - y) < 10
                            = True
                         | otherwise = False
        nextLocation loc = (loc + ((dirToPlayer loc) * (100, 100) * (timeStep, timeStep)))
        dirToPlayer loc = normalizeV (playerPosition - loc)
```

Can one of you point me in the right direction, or am I just too used to imperative languages?

Thanks!

Comment: If your function does not return a score how do you expect it to reset the score? If you want to refactor then I suggest you use a State monad.  If, instead, you want to progress incrementally from your current code then consider making `updateEnemies :: Score -> [Point] -> (Score, [Point])`.  And in the case of a hit you return `(0, updateEnemies xs)`.

Comment: So, what I'm trying to do does not work? I feared as much. Thanks anyways, I'm gonna try something else!

Answer (score 1):

All `updateEnemies` is really doing is applying `nextLocation` to each element of the input list and then discarding the ones that `hitPlayer`.  The main body can thus be reduced to:

```
updateEnemies xs = filter (not . hitPlayer) $ map nextLocation xs
```

or, if you prefer something more points-free:

```
updateEnemies = filter (not . hitPlayer) . map nextLocation
```

In addition, defining `hitPlayer` by using a guard to decide whether to return `True` or `False` is just wrong; the equivalent mistake in other languages would be writing `if (condition) return true; else return false;`.  Just return the result of the test directly!

```
hitPlayer (x, y) = abs (fst newPosition - x) < 10 && abs (snd newPosition - y) < 10
```